# What are the default mutex attributes?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

From man page :

> The `pthread_mutex_init()` function shall initialize the mutex referenced by mutex with attributes specified by attr.
>          ***If attr is NULL, the default mutex attributes are used;*** the effect shall be the same as passing the  address  of  a default  mutex  attributes  object.  Upon successful initialization, the state of the mutex becomes initialized and unlocked.

What are the default mutex attributes?
What gets set with this code: `pthread_mutex_t mutexLock  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dig around inthe POSIX specs to get the defaults for mutex attributes:

- [pthread_mutexattr_settype()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html)

  > `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`
  >
  > Attempting to recursively lock a mutex of this type results in
  >   undefined behaviour. Attempting to unlock a mutex of this type which
  >   was not locked by the calling thread results in undefined behaviour.
  >   Attempting to unlock a mutex of this type which is not locked results
  >   in undefined behaviour. An implementation is allowed to map this mutex
  >   to one of the other mutex types.

  Note that this might be different from the other mutex types, but it could be mapped to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` or `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK`.
- [pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html)

  > The default value of the attribute is `PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE`.

For other attributes, the specs don't seem to clearly state. These attributes are:

- priority ceiling attribute ([`pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling.html))
- protocol attribute for priority inheritance ([`pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.html))

Answer (score 0):

check this link: http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html

```
pthread_mutex_t fastmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t recmutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t errchkmutex = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t recmutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;

pthread_mutex_t errchkmutex = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```